# Failed to build a release apk in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to build a release apk in React Native. But the process is failing.
I tried doing `./gradlew clean` and deleting the `android/app/build` directory.

Error I am getting is:

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
means you have some syntax error in javascript, so node is unable to package that.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following command

**SOLUTION-1**

```
./gradlew clean && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease
```

**SOLUTION-2**

```
- cd android && ./gradlew clean
- gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

Comment: Still the same error. No help! :(

Comment: @SumanBhattarai try 2nd solution

Comment: I already did that too. That will generate the release apk successfully but when I install the apk on my emulator and open it, it crashes before opening.

Comment: @SumanBhattarai Try installing in device

Comment: crashing on real device too.

Comment: @SumanBhattarai There might be some coding issue in it, while building the APK issue was fixed right?

Comment: I have been running the app using the run-android & run-ios command in my emulator & simulator and the app is working perfectly fine. I am just getting this error while generating release apk.

Comment: Check if there were any unwanted imports like babel or something there in anywhere in written code, if so, remove and rebuild